# Compile kernel driver failed when processing __user

Tags: compiler-errors, linux-kernel, driver

I get a compile error when compiling a kernel driver.The error info is

```
pxa270_gpio_led_drv.c|27 col 70| error: expected ‘;’, ‘,’ or ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
||  static ssize_t SIMPLE_GPIO_LED_read ( struct file *file, char __user *buf, size_t count, loff_t *offset)
```

Part of the source file is:

```
static ssize_t SIMPLE_GPIO_LED_read ( struct file *file, char __user *buf, size_t count, loff_t *offset) 
{
#ifdef OURS_GPIO_LED_DEBUG 
printk ("SIMPLE_GPIO_LED_read [ --kernel--]\n"); 
#endif 
return count; 
}
```

The compile command is :

```
 gcc -c -Wall -O -D__KERNEL__ -DMODULE -I/home/test/Desktop/linux-2.4.21/include   pxa270_gpio_led_drv.c -o pxa270_gpio_led_drv.o
```

Can anyone help me? Thanks.

Comment: It looks like you're missing an include. The one that defines `__user`, going by the column number in the error message.

Comment: Why do you think that this driver can be compiled for a 2.4 kernel?

Comment: I need to study more!

Answer (score 0):

Have you included `<linux/types.h>` that defines `loff_t` ?

The `__user` macro is an instruction to gcc and doesn't require inclusion of a header.